# Add icon to a (link) element / element in element

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I need to create an element that renders to this HTML, so that the icon is part of the `a`'s inner HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="/pricing/de" id="de">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Deutschland
    </a>
</li>
```

My current approach is the following

```
<li th:each="country : ${countryList}">
    <a th:href="@{country.getKey()}" th:text="${country.getValue()}">
        <i th:class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

But that of course overrides the icon with the `th:text`. Adding the icon to the text doesn't seem to work either...

How do I do that in thymeleaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a many ways to handle this.  I would probably do this:

```
<li th:each="country : ${countryList}">
    <a th:href="@{country.key}" >
        <i th:class="fa fa-square-o"></i><span th:text="${country.value}" />
    </a>
</li>
```

But you might not want the extra span, so you could use a th:block.

```
<li th:each="country : ${countryList}">
    <a th:href="@{country.key}">
        <i th:class="fa fa-square-o"></i><th:block th:text="${country.value}" />
    </a>
</li>
```

Or just inline the text itself.

```
<li th:each="country : ${countryList}">
    <a th:href="@{country.key}" th:inline="text">
        <i th:class="fa fa-square-o"></i>[[${country.value}]]
    </a>
</li>
```

edit: Also, if you naming your properties according to JavaBeans conventions, you should just use .key instead of .getKey()